# Directing google maps to load a kml file from a url

Tags: file, server, loading, google-maps-urls

I have a site ([BoatingTrax.com](http://www.boatingtrax.com)) which places notices to mariners on several maps (Google Earth and Google maps). I upload each map daily in kml format to my server. Google Earth works well and updates daily. Google Maps doesn't. I need it to load a new maps from the server location. I tried a scripting file a attached. Any help greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a good tutorial on creating KML layers on maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

I did an example with your downloadable kml for SEQ. So when you update the earth kml files. the map should also update.

You may have to deal with cache parameters.

[image: example of map with kml layer]